# Chef + Chocolatey - "No candidate version available for (package)"

Tags: chef-infra, chocolatey

We've been using Chef and Chocolatey separately for a while and recently started using them together to easily install some Windows packages.

For example:

```
include_recipe 'chocolatey::default'

chocolatey_package 'git.install' do
  action :install
end

chocolatey_package 'nuget.commandline' do
  action :install
end

chocolatey_package 'docker-compose' do
  action :install
  version '1.21.2'
end

chocolatey_package 'gitlab-runner' do
  action :install
  version '11.0.0'
end
```

That recipe has worked, but now we've been getting these errors without any other changes:

```
* chocolatey_package[git.install] action install
  - install version 2.18.0 of package git.install
* chocolatey_package[nuget.commandline] action install
  - install version 4.8.1 of package nuget.commandline
* chocolatey_package[docker-compose] action install
  - install version 1.21.2 of package docker-compose
* chocolatey_package[gitlab-runner] action install
  * No candidate version available for gitlab-runner
  ================================================================================
  Error executing action `install` on resource 'chocolatey_package[gitlab-runner]'
  ================================================================================

  Chef::Exceptions::Package
  -------------------------
  No candidate version available for gitlab-runner
```

Note the successful installs, followed by a failure.

That initially happened for the `git` package, and out of frustration, I changed it to `git.install`, which worked. But now it just started happening with `gitlab-runner`.

Has anyone seen this type of failure where it works one day and not the next? I've verified the package exists and I can manually pull it down with `choco install`.

My next troubleshooting step might be to dig into that resource; I know that error message can happen with package installs on Linux platforms, so maybe the error description is misleading...  i.e. `chocolatey_package` is either throwing the exception or the handler is doing too general of a catch (to use .NET terms).

Comment: Assuming that this is happening in the last 1 hour or so, it could be related to some issues with the performance of the site: http://status.chocolatey.org/

Comment: @GaryEwanPark That is worth keeping an eye on but it started last week with the `git` package and now happens *only* with the `gitlab-runner`one. Thanks for mentioning though... as that must be why I'm unable to do more testing :)

Comment: Is your setup within an organisation? Or a personal setup?

Comment: It is a personal setup... just a basic Chocolatey install and using the public repository. But... I did just have a successful run. The timing of success coincides with the chocolatey.org issues clearing up, but for me this issue started yesterday and also happened last week. I guess it could have still been a stability issue with the site/repo?

Comment: Could have been. Other known outages are listed on the status page. The reason I asked is that, while we try to keep things working, there is no guarantee of the site being up. That is where we recommend bringing packages in house so that things always work.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most annoying issues I've ever faced.  Chocolatey.org is very unreliable, indeed.  However, I can directly install on the command-line immediately following this error, but through the chocolatey_package chef resource, it fails with the dreaded "No candidate version available" pretty much every time, regardless of the state of chocolatey.org.  Hopefully, Chef eventually get their act together.  In the meantime, here's a workaround that has worked for me for quite some time.

```
choco source add -n=local -s"[PATH]" -u=[USERNAME] -p=[PASSWORD]
```

Then go to chocolatey.org, find your package, download it to that location, and then rerun your recipe.  This works very well, because you no longer depend on external resources nearly as much and it's faster, but keep in mind that when new packages are released, you'll more than likely need to refresh with the latest packages.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you running into this problem today, try to update Chef. This problem might be due to a `choco.exe` v1 vs v2 issue. v2 now requires using `search -r` instead of `list -r` to find uninstalled packages:

```
PS C:\> choco --version
2.2.2
PS C:\> choco search -r visualstudio2019buildtools
visualstudio2019buildtools|16.11.29
PS C:\> choco list -r visualstudio2019buildtools
visualstudio-installer|2.0.3
```

https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/13833 fixed this in Chef v18.2.41.

https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/13928 backported this to Chef v17.10.82.

Note that unless `choco.exe` is in the PATH, you might run into a regression with the `choco --version` check that will be fixed with https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/13935.